# Do action when user does not interact

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**My problem is as follows:** sometimes my users don't interact, or they do not do any event, so for secure them, I should log-out the user because the user has sensitive data.

Is there any function from flutter do the same thing?

**Conclusion :** if the user open my application and keep the application open without any action or interact for any reason, I want of the application to count 5 min if no interacts from the user, the application should do some actions.

I checked of AppLifecycleState, but it does not help in my case.
AppLifecycleState works if the application in background or open again.

Comment: see `GestureBinding` mixin, for example you can override its `handleEvent` method

Comment: Can you give me an example please for `GestureBinding`?, I did some searches but I do not find a clear example.

Comment: see `ImageCache` documentation - it shows how to plug a custom `WidgetsFlutterBindings` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer to do something like that.

If user don't press button then after 5 minutes it will print Something in log and if user click before it then it will not do anything.

```
Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 5), (time) {
      print('Something');
    });
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("press"),
          onPressed: () {
            timer.cancel();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I did the same thing and I faced some issues, it is ok I can control it.
Is this way the best practice? can I trust of this way ?

Comment: what issues you face? this is best practice to do such type of task.

Comment: One of the issues is timer still working when user move to another page or two timers working together.

Comment: You have to cancel timer in dispose method, i added code now it will not create same issue.

Comment: Thanks.
Another issue : when user goes from screen 1 to screen 2 and the timer in screen 1 is canceled and user go back from screen 2 to screen 1 the timer does not work again in screen 1.

Comment: It happens because when you came back from other screen then init method will not called, so this issue happen. I suggest you to navigate using push replacement when you navigate from this screen and navigate to this screen again using navigate.pushreplacement.

Comment: I found this solution to fix go back issue :


Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => addLocation()
                  )
              ).then((_){
                callAnyMethod();
              });

Comment: Yes you can also restart timer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an minimal working example I wrote for this case without any state management, you could try It in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/). You'll logout If user is idle after 5 secs.

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LogoutTimerModel timerModel;
  Timer logoutTimer;

  int page = 1; // you could use enum
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerModel = LogoutTimerModel();
    timerModel.updateTimestamp(DateTime.now());
    logoutTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (time) {
      DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
      if(currentTime.difference(timerModel.timestamp).inSeconds > 5) {
        setState((){
          page = 0;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Listener(
        onPointerDown: (PointerEvent details) {
          timerModel.updateTimestamp(DateTime.now());
        },
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            if(page == 1)
              return LoginPage();
            else
              return LogoutPage();
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Login now, but wait for timeout to logout...")
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LogoutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Logout now")
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LogoutTimerModel {
  DateTime timestamp;

  void updateTimestamp(DateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }
}
```

Because your case seems like a global operation, you should do It in `MyApp`, and wrap It with `Listener` to reset the timestamp, that's all the concepts.

**Edit:**
For someone who think Listener will be absorbed by normal button click event, here is the test:

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LogoutTimerModel timerModel;
  Timer logoutTimer;

  int page = 1; // you could use enum
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timerModel = LogoutTimerModel();
    timerModel.updateTimestamp(DateTime.now());
    logoutTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (time) {
      DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
      if(currentTime.difference(timerModel.timestamp).inSeconds > 5) {
        setState((){
          page = 0;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Listener(
        onPointerDown: (PointerEvent details) {
          timerModel.updateTimestamp(DateTime.now());
          print("Omitted??");
        },
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            if(page == 1)
              return LoginPage();
            else
              return LogoutPage();
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Login now, but wait for timeout to logout..."),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("case"),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Omit???");
              }
            )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LogoutPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Logout now")
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LogoutTimerModel {
  DateTime timestamp;

  void updateTimestamp(DateTime timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
Omitted??
Omit???
```

By the way, I didn't test code in all ways, so If someone find something could affect `Listener`, feel free to make comments to help others.

**Notice:**
You might want to get passed like `showDialog`, you could wrap `Listener` above `MaterialApp` depends on requirement.

```dart
Listener(child: MaterailApp ...
```

Comment: and what about any UI widgets that absorb pointer events? a button for example, if you have a button and click on it your listener will never be fired

Comment: @pskink, Normal button click will not affect `Listener`, but If you absorb or interact with that deep, you'll need to handle It manually, there is no bullet to kill everything I think...

Comment: ok normal button works fine but `AbsorbPointer` does not - `Listener` is not getting any events

Comment: `AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer` should do there job correctly, I think this is expected, and we should handle It manually, thanks for the comment.

Comment: seems that any dialog blocks it too (shown with `showDialog` function), it's really better to use general solution like `GestureBinding` mixin

Comment: Thanks for comment, you'll get passed If you wrap the `Listener` above `MaterialApp`, thanks for reminding me to notice this :P By the way,  you could provide an answer about `GestureBinding` , I'm willing to see more answers :D

Comment: `class MyWidgetsFlutterBinding extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, HitTestEntry entry) {
    super.handleEvent(event, entry);
    if (event is PointerDownEvent) {
      print(event.timeStamp);
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  MyWidgetsFlutterBinding();
  runApp(...);
}`

Comment: Hey, not provide in comment, but in answer! you might get accepted by op, I won't give you an accepted answer :P